# How to refresh Datagridview in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my VB.net win form application, when I clicked Load button I am displaying a filename from a folder onto a Datagridview. Then after I click on Process button the file will be moved to another folder. After file has been moved, Grid has to be refreshed.

Here is the code i have written. I can able to move the file but not refreshing the Grid.Any suggestions please?

```
 Public Class Form1
 Private Sub Load_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles Load.Click

    With DataGridView1
        .Columns.Add("Column 0", "TaskName")
        .AutoResizeColumns()
    End With

    Dim rowint As Integer = 0

    'Dim directoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\Desktop\auto")
    'Dim fileInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryInfo.ToString)
    'Dim name As String

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt")
    DataGridView1.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename
    rowint = rowint + 1

End Sub

Private Sub Process_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Process.Click
    System.IO.File.Move("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt", "C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\Demo\abc.txt")
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt")
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Refresh()` method only redraws the existing grid to the screen again. You will need to reload the grid's data by performing a "click". This can be done by calling the event directly or by using the `PerformClick()` method.

```
Private Sub Process_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Process.Click
    System.IO.File.Move("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt", "C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\Demo\abc.txt")
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt")
    Load_Click(Load, Nothing)
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

---- or ----

```
Private Sub Process_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Process.Click
    System.IO.File.Move("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt", "C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\Demo\abc.txt")
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt")
    Load.PerformClick()
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work as the load.PerformClick will look at the old field?

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr: Possibly, but as I'm looking at it I would say the logic for that event should probably be extracted out anyway to enable the type of rebinding that is necessary. The point stands though, `Refresh()` only redraws. If he wants to redisplay the grid data, he'll need to call a method that rebinds the grid.

Comment: Agreed, it would be better to do it via binding

Comment: PerformClick does not work. Has anyone found a working solution to refreshing a DataGrid after the datasource data has changed without a manual click?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not binding to anything, it would be best to just change the value of the row in the grid.

The better alternative would be to create a List and then set your datasource to that, and when you update the list item to reflect the new string, you can then refresh the grid and it should work.

```
Private Sub Process_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Process.Click    
    System.IO.File.Move("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt", "C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\Demo\abc.txt")    
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt")    
    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0) = "C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\auto\INQUEUE\123.txt"    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- make a default sub fillgrid()
- call it after any update
- it reload your grid

Answer (score 0):

You will need an event for example a button click. To keep this simple in the button event make the `datagridview = yourtableAdptor.getdata();` This will keep the view up-to-date as long as the insert statements are before the getdata sample code.

For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal pay = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    string comment = textBox2.Text;

    payTableAdapter.Insert(dateTimePicker1.Value, pay, comment);

    payDataGridView.DataSource = payTableAdapter.GetData();

    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
}
```